# How to receive data into other locations

Tags: javacard

I want to know how to receive data into another variable, not the APDU buffer.

It is possible call the method `setIncomingAndReceive()` or `receiveBytes()` to receive data into the APDU buffer. But I want for card to receive data into another variable, not the APDU buffer.

In case of sending a reponse APDU, the method `sendBytesLong(byte[] outData, short bOff, short len)` supports  sending data from other array variables, not APDU buffer. But it seems that there is no method which supports receiving data into other variables.

I hope somebody knows the method or the sample code to receive the data into the other variable.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you would want to do that? The next call to `process()` will restart with the APDU buffer reset anyway. Maybe we know a workaround for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that. If you need to copy the incoming data to another buffer, simply copy it using `Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic()`.

Side note: `APDU.sendBytesLong()` copies the data from your buffer into the APDU buffer and  then sends it out. This API is provided just so that you don't have to do the copy in your applet.

Comment: You can use `\`method()\`` for code (or `<code>method()</code>` of course).